# Why is my sql command giving me a wrong data type error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

This is my code

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Patient SET FirstName ='" + tbPatientFirstName.Text + "' WHERE PatientID='" + tbPatientID+ "' ",conn);
```

The text I'm an changing in the tbPatientFirstName is from a string to a string. The PatientID is the records primary key.
I know I'm not using parameterised sql but its not required and I don't have time to learn it at the moment

Comment: Use parameterized queries, don't concatenate strings to build your sql query.

Comment: How does the string look when it's time to execute?

Comment: Is `PatientID` really a `string`? You probably want to remove the `''`.

Comment: is `PatientID` an integer? because you are building your query as if it was a string/varchar: `UPDATE Patient SET FirstName ='john' WHERE PatientID='id??'`

Comment: probably because PatientID is an int but your code is forcing it to text.

Comment: then there is no need for the single quotes

Comment: parameterized queries will help you find problems like this sooner.

Comment: What is your `tbPatientID`?

Comment: You think that you don't need parameterized query? Are you kidding? What if someone types a first name with a single quote in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the suggestion to use `paramterized query` (which you believe is not needed, so *hopefully* it is OK), three things seem to be the potential causes of the error.

First, you seem to use the `TextBox` object rather than its `Text`. Change `tbPatientID` to `tbPatientID.Text`

Secondly, if your `PatientID` is integer, you may need to remove the apostrophe `'` for the `tbPatientID`

```
WHERE PatientID=" + tbPatientID.Text.Trim()+ " " //no apostrophe
```

Thirdly, to avoid having `whitespace` undetected, consider using `Trim()`:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Patient SET FirstName ='" + tbPatientFirstName.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE PatientID=" + tbPatientID.Text.Trim()+ " ",conn);
```

Comment: @SimonKarlsson strange, I found the code (`tbPatientID`) and his explanation `PatientID` inconsistent...

Comment: Adding .Text and removing the single quotes solves the problem

Comment: @JerryMurphy great! ;) so it is really TextBox after all. Please consider if you are going to use your application for some one else, parameterized query is a must.

Comment: I will learn how to use them when I can squeeze in the time. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JerryMurphy ;) take your time... otherwise, the app will be vulnerable to SQL injection which can potentially destroy your whole database. :)

Comment: I know but I have 5 other projects due in the next few weeks so if i can i will revisit the program before i submit I will change to parameterized queries. I had never even heard of them until yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The time required to use a parameterized query is a lot less than the time required to fix these errors

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Patient 
       SET FirstName =@name WHERE PatientID= @id", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = tbPatientFirstName.Text 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(tbPatientID.Text);
```

And that's all is required. Now you don't have troubles in passing values to your database engine also if these values contains a single quote.